# How to use startAt(double value, String key) and endAt(double value, String key) Firebase RealTime Database in Android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to do a query by using `orderByChild` and also filtering with the key of those child. In this case, my keys and values are both data that works for querying what I want.

My problem is presented when the keys contains numbers, if the keys only have letters, then there is no problem. I'm trying to maintain always letters along the numbers since I read the recommendation in [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39085361/4017501) directly from a firebaser.

My json is:

```js
{
  "my_list":{
    "100xyz":{
      "value1": 100,
      "value2": 100,
      "name":"100xyz"
    },
    "200xyz":{
      "value1": 200,
      "value2": 200,
      "name":"200xyz"
    },
    "300xyz":{
      "value1": 300,
      "value2": 300,
      "name":"300xyz"
    },
    "400xyz":{
      "value1": 400,
      "value2": 400,
      "name":"400xyz"
    },
    "500xyz":{
      "value1": 500,
      "value2": 500,
      "name":"500xyz"
    }
  }
}
```

My code is:

```
DatabaseReference root = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().getRoot();
DatabaseReference list = root.child("my_list");
list.orderByChild("value2").startAt(100, "100xyz").endAt(500, "200xyz").addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
        SomeModel someModel = dataSnapshot.getValue(SomeModel.class);
        Log.d("SOME_MODEL", someModel.getName());
    }
});
```

The problem is I can see 4 childs in the console:

```
D/SOME_MODEL: 100xyz
D/SOME_MODEL: 200xyz
D/SOME_MODEL: 300xyz
D/SOME_MODEL: 400xyz
```

But I should only be seen 2

```
D/SOME_MODEL: 100xyz
D/SOME_MODEL: 200xyz
```

I want to emphazise: it does works, as long as the keys don't have numbers.

How can I filter by orderByChild and key at the same time when the keys have numbers?

Comment: Since I'm likely the Firebaser that answered in the question you speak about (a link is always appreciated when you refer to another question), I'd love to help. Can you reduce your question to a single JSON with a single corresponding code sample that reproduce the problem?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen sorry for skipping the link, I'm trying to solve this since yesterday, little tired by now. I have applied the editions you have suggested. Please, let me know if there is anything else I can do to improve my question.

Comment: Why are you not using `startAt(String value, String key)`? What do you think the `double` value means?

Comment: @cricket_007 because my "value2" is a double so is better to look it up that way. To give you more context, I'm trying to do something like GeoFire does "value1" will be my latitude, "value2" my longitude, and the key will be a combination of both. That way I can orderByChild("longitude"), but only in a range of latitude (the key). Do you think the problem is the double? Because the problem is only happening when the keys have numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to think that passing two arguments to `endAt()` makes the query end at whichever of the value or key comes first. That is not how queries work in Firebase.

The second argument to `endAt()` is only used after the query finds nodes that match the first argument.

So when you're passing `endAt(500, "200xyz")`, the database first filters on nodes with `value2` equal to `value2` (the first argument). This means it finds this node as the end of the query:

```
"500xyz":{
  "value1": 500,
  "value2": 500,
  "name":"500xyz"
}
```

It then uses the key `200xyz` (the second argument) to determine whether to include this node or not (technically: where in the list of multiple nodes to end returning). Since the key `200xyz` is before `500xyz` the query result doesn't include this node, resulting in:

```
"100xyz":{
  "value1": 100,
  "value2": 100,
  "name":"100xyz"
},
"200xyz":{
  "value1": 200,
  "value2": 200,
  "name":"200xyz"
},
"300xyz":{
  "value1": 300,
  "value2": 300,
  "name":"300xyz"
},
"400xyz":{
  "value1": 400,
  "value2": 400,
  "name":"400xyz"
},
```

Also see:

- [Firebase orderByChild with startAt()'s second argument w/ pagination not odering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31995881/firebase-orderbychild-with-startats-second-argument-w-pagination-not-odering):
- [Limiting the firebase equalTo query with the optional key parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43764292/limiting-the-firebase-equalto-query-with-the-optional-key-parameter)
- [Firebase Query order by and start at name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43376331/firebase-query-order-by-and-start-at-name/43376894#43376894)
- [How to paging query from Firebase using Android FirebaseUI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41278544/how-to-paging-query-from-firebase-using-android-firebaseui/41285470#41285470)