# how 2 pass two parameters in end_at() query for python firebase-admin

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-admin

I need to sort the data in descending order based on the timestamp and keys(which are autogenerated by firebase).

I tried the answer given in the question. But it throws an error that endAt() takes only one parameter.

[How to use startAt(double value, String key) and endAt(double value, String key) Firebase RealTime Database in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45625553/how-to-use-startatdouble-value-string-key-and-endatdouble-value-string-key?answertab=oldest#tab-top)

How should i pass two parameters in the method.

Comment: Firebase Database queries can only order/filter on a single property. In many cases it is possible to combine the values you want to filter on into a single (synthetic) property. For an example of this and other approaches, see my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26700924/query-based-on-multiple-where-clauses-in-firebase

Comment: The second parameter to `endAt` would not allow you specify a second sort order anyway. It merely allows you to pass in a tie-breaker key at which to stop in case there are multiple items with the same timestmap.