# Search firebase realtime database base on 6 digit in front of the child data, i want to query data between two numbers (dates)

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-platform

Is there possible to search database on 6 first digits from the Realtime Database, something like I search for 211010 and the data in range/having the 211010 in front of it will show up like 211010XXXXXXX, 211010XXXXXXX, I want to query data between two numbers (dates).

[image]
the 211010 was a date 2021-10-10

Answer (score 1):

You might be tempted to use a query that looks like this:

```
DatabaseReference db = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference pendingRef = db.child("Pending");
Query queryByKey = pendingRef.orderByKey().startAt("211010");
```

But this will not provide the expected results. Why? Because of the reason provided by @FrankvanPuffelen in the following answer:

- [Firebase OrderByKey with startAt and endAt giving wrong results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39076284/firebase-orderbykey-with-startat-and-endat-giving-wrong-results)

So to solve this, the best option that you have is **not** to use only numerical values for the keys. So a simple solution would be to prefix the keys with a constant String. So the corresponding query should look like this:

```
Query queryByKey = pendingRef.orderByKey().startAt("*211010").endAt("*211010" + "\uf8ff");
//
```

And the keys in the database should look like this:

```
Firebase-root
  |
  --- *211010...
  |
  --- *211010...
  |
  --- *211010...
```

**Edit:**

I just took the following example:

```
{
  "Pending" : {
    "2110101" : {
      "name" : 1
    },
    "2110102" : {
      "name" : 2
    },
    "2110103" : {
      "name" : 3
    },
    "2110114" : { //It's 21-10-11 and not  //It's 21-10-10
      "name" : 4
    },
  }
}
```

Using the following query (no `*` added before the number):

```
Query queryByKey = pendingRef.orderByKey().startAt("211010").endAt("211010" + "\uf8ff");
```

I get the following result:

```
name: 1
name: 2
name: 3
name: 4
```

So I get all results. However, when I use:

```
{
  "Pending" : {
    "*2110101" : {
      "name" : 1
    },
    "*2110102" : {
      "name" : 2
    },
    "*2110103" : {
      "name" : 3
    },
    "*2110114" : { //It's 21-10-11 and not  //It's 21-10-10
      "name" : 4
    },
  }
}
```

And the following query (with the `*` added before):

```
Query queryByKey = pendingRef.orderByKey().startAt("*211010").endAt("*211010" + "\uf8ff");
```

I only get:

```
name: 1
name: 2
name: 3
```

So it works in this case as well.

Comment: so i need to put an simbol infront of data that i would save?, and what if i search for 211010 and for the next 3 days like 211013

Comment: Yes, that's correct. I choose to use `*`, but you can choose whatever you want, as long as it's not numeric. Give it a try and tell me if it works.

Comment: okok letme try it and gonna tell you if it works :)

Comment: Ok, looking forward to seeing your feedback.

Comment: Hey @AlexMamo. Great answer as usual  --- I doubt that the SDK will coerce to an array in this situation, given the size of the keys. That problem really only occurs when the keys/query results start close to `0`, which seems like it can't happen here.

Comment: Hey @FrankvanPuffelen Thank you. I did a quick test, as in my updated answer and it works as I originally thought.

Comment: @billy Hey. Have you tried my solution above, does it work?

Comment: Tbh, im stuck on the date picker design, because the 211013 was a date, stuck on the dateformat rn i need to get a complete 211013 not 13/20/21, i've using (DateFormat.SHORT).format(Calender.getInstance().getTime()) maybe if you know how to, can help me ?

Comment: Try to use [SimpleDateFormat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3056703/simpledateformat-ignoring-month-when-parsing) and format it as you like. Give it a try and tell me if it works.

Comment: Have solved the issue? Is now everything alright?

Comment: i can pick the datepicker alrd, but i got another issue on the date i want to pick, when i try to pick the date 21 10 01 it will be turn into 21 10 1, the zero will affect everything

Comment: That's most likely a format issue. So please add a new question, here on Stackoverflow to get a proper formation. And keep me posted, ok?