# Something goes wrong with my startAt and endAt search data in range, its show all my data inside of firebase

Tags: java, firebase, android-studio, firebase-realtime-database, adapter

so i write a code for searching some range of data in my realtime firebase and when i did that, the data that shown up its not only in range, but all data that i have in firebase is out to my cardview(fragment)

this is my main code that work for searching data

```
public class SearchListView extends AppCompatActivity {

    private RecyclerView recView;
    MyAdapter adapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate (savedInstanceState);
        setContentView (R.layout.activity_search_list_view);

        String tanggalawal = getIntent ( ).getStringExtra ("tanggalawal");
        String tanggalakhir = getIntent ( ).getStringExtra ("tanggalakhir");

        DatabaseReference db = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
        DatabaseReference pendingRef = db.child("Users").child("Pending");

        Query queryByKey = pendingRef.orderByKey()
                .startAt("*" + tanggalawal)
                .endAt("*"+ tanggalakhir + "\uf8ff");


        recView = (RecyclerView)findViewById (R.id.recview);
        recView.setLayoutManager (new LinearLayoutManager (this));

        FirebaseRecyclerOptions<Model> options =
                new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<Model>()
                        .setQuery(queryByKey, Model.class)
                        .build();

        adapter = new MyAdapter (options);
        recView.setAdapter (adapter);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        adapter.startListening();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        adapter.stopListening();
    }

}
```

and my firebase look like this

[Firebase Database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/io9pp.png)

and this is my adapter code

```
public class MyAdapter extends FirebaseRecyclerAdapter <Model,MyAdapter.myViewHolder>{

    public MyAdapter(@NonNull FirebaseRecyclerOptions<Model> options) {
        super (options);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull myViewHolder myViewHolder, int i, @NonNull Model model) {
        myViewHolder.currentDate.setText (model.getCurrentDate ());
        myViewHolder.fullName.setText (model.getFullName ());
        myViewHolder.currentDateandTime.setText (model.getCurrentDateandTime ());
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public myViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from (parent.getContext ()).inflate (R.layout.item,parent,false);
        return new myViewHolder (view);
    }

    class myViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        TextView currentDate, fullName, currentDateandTime;
        public myViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super (itemView);
            currentDate = (TextView)itemView.findViewById (R.id.tvTanggalPengajuan);
            fullName = (TextView)itemView.findViewById (R.id.tvNama);
            currentDateandTime = (TextView)itemView.findViewById (R.id.tvNomorkontrak);
        }
    }
    public interface OnNoteListener{

        void OnNoteListener(int position);

    }

}
```

i've following this method using "*" that look like this, but still failed
[Search firebase realtime database base on 6 digit in front of the child data, i want to query data between two numbers (dates)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70077152/search-firebase-realtime-database-base-on-6-digit-in-front-of-the-child-data-i)

Comment: What is the value of `tanggalawal`?

Comment: its a date in 20211211 format, and the same as tanggalakhir

Comment: Why do you say *its not only in range*? Please provide a concrete example in your question.

Comment: something like i have 5 data inside the firebase, and i want to take only 1 data base on date, but when i pick the date and process that, they give me all 5 data. and when i choose something that not in database. they still give me 5 data

Comment: Have you tried the solution in the linked answer using the exact same data?

Comment: so i change my database look like the exact on the link answer?

Comment: Give it a try and tell me if it works.

Comment: its work if i only put `*20211211`, but how can i take the rest of number behind the 11. i should use equalTo?

Comment: No, it should work as expected. Add more numbers at the end.

Comment: i try to add 00000000 and it still the same, i make it look like this,   .startAt("*" + tanggalawal + "00000000")

Comment: Aren't the following records returned?

Comment: wdym, which records?, when i did the + "00000000" its back look like the first one, the all data is showing up

Comment: uhm so what should i do @AlexMamo